# UITableView deciding individual row height

Tags: ios, uitableview, model-view-controller, uikit

I have a tableview with customized header sections and cells. I have created my model, and right now the model keeps a reference to the section view header, which is "bad" design, but I actually just followed sample code from apple. Well, my cell has a label witch will hold multi lined data, and so it should be resized so every line is visible. I guess that would be the controllers job, with heightForRowAtIndexPath right? As a fact that wouldn't be difficult to just retrieve the cell from there and get its height from there. However, that is not possible as for the fact that the cell is not created yet. (Correct me if I am wrong)

The only way I can think of this to work would be to make a reference to the cell in my model, Yes I know, bad citizen. But in that way I could easily get the height I need.

Another way would be to create a method that would calculate the height with sizeWithAttributes:, but that really seems to be bad design, as I shouldn't know my views appearance.

Am I overseeing something basic here? Or is it just the way it is.

I didn't attach any code because, I don't know what you would want, but feel free to ask me to insert something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call cellForRowAtIndexPath to get the specified result.
I believe you are using an *array* or an *array of dictionaries* to hold the content,

Let the array be

```
   NSArray *arrData = [[NSArray alloc]init];
```

Now, in

```
**heightForRowAtIndexPath**
{
   if ( [[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].length] < 30 )
     return 40;  // Initial height
   else    if ( [[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].length] > 30 )
     return 60;   // Or any other value as per your need

}
```

This would resize the height of the cell, depending on the length of the string inside that cell.
And, in **cellForRowAtIndexPath**
use

```
[cell.lblText setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
```

// If you wish to make it more dynamic

in **heightForRowAtIndex** write

```
{
 int _iCount = [[self.arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].length] % 40;

if ( _iCount == 0 )
return 40;
else
 return 40*_iCount;
}
```

This would solve it.

Comment: So is there a "real" way to calculate the height of that particular string. I know I can use sizeWithAttributes: (sizeWithFont is depricated), and set a font as an attribute. But say I use a unknown font, how would I then calculate the height? I think your logic is valid, but it doesn't work in practice. You will save my day if you can answer this comment though :) Thanks for the answer as well. Very much appreciated

Comment: What happens in this scenario is, that the height gets calculated automatically depending on the Font size AND the number of lines for the label, that is calculated from the width of the cell or the uilabel in this case. So, you can just calculate the length of the string, and the rest are fixed.

Comment: I don't get it. You are returning 40 no matter what? Wouldn't that make the cell's height 40 always?.

Comment: I see your edit. But wont it result in endless nested if statements. I mean, the textlabel's length could be everything from 0 to 1000000 lines (just hypothetically)

Comment: It need not be that long. I suggest you use a UILabel on the cell. Editing the portion in the answer.. CHECK,..

Comment: Now we are talking :) Thanks for the effort ! Really good job.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cell is already created when the heightForRowAtIndexPath is called. So in that method you can get the cell, calculate the height of the label and return the correct height for the tableviewCell.

Comment: Problem is, that calling cellForRowAtIndexPath: inside heightForRowAtIndexPath: will cause a crash.